# Can't find an API which gives me a full list of cryptocurrencies ordered by market cap

Tags: api, currencies, market

I need to know the top-10 crytocurrencies ordered by market cap so I am looking for an api that returns a list of coins ordered that way.
Does anyone know?

Comment: Welcome to Bitocin.SE! I see you already have an answer, you are on your way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this [website](https://coinmarketcap.com/). I think it what you're looking for.